# MSMQ over HTTP - Access Denied 401 Error

Tags: c#, http, iis, msmq, windows-server-2012

I am using MSMQ to send messages over the http protocol with message redirection to send acknowledgments to an IP address. This setup works with Windows 10 but there is an issue using Windows Server 2012 R2. Messages are being sent and received but the acknowledgements fail to send on the receiving end. The Unacknowledged count on the sending Outgoing Queue will not decrease.

> @"FormatName:DIRECT=http://{0}/msmq/PRIVATE$/queue_name_{1}";

Redirect xml:

```
<StreamReceiptSetup xmlns="msmq-streamreceipt-mapping.xml">
<setup>
<LogicalAddress>http://*/msmq/PRIVATE$/queue_name_*</LogicalAddress><StreamReceiptURL>http://192.168.0.101/msmq/PRIVATE$/order_queue$</StreamReceiptURL>
</setup>
</StreamReceiptSetup>
```

When attempting to access MSMQ through a browser at:

> < ipAddrress >/MSMQ

Receiving the 401 error:

> Error message 401.3: You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials you supplied (access denied due to Access Control Lists). Ask the Web server's administrator to give you access to 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\msmq'.

IIS log:

> 2017-07-05 15:56:57 192.168.0.100 55518 192.168.0.101 80 HTTP/1.1 POST /msmq/private$/order_queue$?senderstream=2liqbhfjifrethbx1mmtxnquvn8gv1dscy4spazo5i0za2fj 404 - NotFound -

Using Windows 10 the expected 501 error is received. What could cause the 401.3 error on Windows Server 2012 R2?